# How does git handle modularization?

Tags: git

It's not that I'm confused, but ignorant, although I may become confused after my ignorance is cured. This question concerns how git handles modularization.

Suppose I'm automating a reporting tool (which I am), and I output the reports in PDF. My directory structure has one file, which is the main module, like this:

```
main.pl
```

In main.pl, I trigger output like this:

```
print_output($ref_to_data);
```

After a while, other users want the benefit of the report automation, but they require output in Excel and HTML. I modularize my code by adding output modules, so that my directory structure now looks like this:

```
main.pl
main_v1.pl
PDF.pl
Excel.pl
HTML.pl
```

And in the main_V1 code, I trigger the output functions like this:

```
PDF::print_output($ref_to_data);
Excel::print_output($ref_to_data);
HTML::print_output($ref_to_data);
```

Using git for version control for this is not a problem. Git works like a charm. But more time passes, and now I have to hand off my code to others in different departments. This application is now pushing 9 KLOC, and I want to refactor to separate the different forms of output. The code to output PDF, Excel, and HTML isn't trivial, and I don't want to burden the maintainers with unnecessary stuff.

I would like to create three branches, with three versions of main, like this:

```
# PDF branch
main_V2.pl
PDF.pl

# Excel branch
main_V2.pl
Excel.pl

# HTML branch
main_V2.pl
HTML.pl
```

I can do this by creating three new directories, copying all the code into them, initializing a git repository in each of them, and go from there. However, I should be able to create three branches in the same directory. That way, when I work on main_V2.pl in the PDF branch, it won't contain the Excel or HTML code, and when I work on main_V2.pl in the Excel branch, it won't contain the PDF or the HTML code. My question is, if I fire up main_V2.pl in one branch, how will git know that I mean that particular branch version?

Is this even possible? Or should I just bite the bullet and create three new directories?

Comment: You can do lots of things with git. Branches, sub-projects. But none of them seem worthwhile for this case. It sounds like splitting the code up like you suggest will cause pain regardless how you do it. If you are sharing the code with people who will also maintain it, then splitting it up will make it more difficult to share fixes and enhancements. With a small project like this it's generally much easier to keep it together, and let the other teams fork the repo or work in branches and let you manage acceptance of their changes back to the main.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is: ***Git doesn't handle modularlization, Perl does***.

You can easily do what you want in Git. However, before I go into how to do it, I first have to address your example: it's a bad use of branching. You should leave your code as it is.

You say you want to reduce the maintenance burden for future programmers, but you've already done that by isolating the different formatters into their own files. A programmer can handle this just fine. Your code is already modularlized. If you modularize with branching it will be very difficult for one project to output *TWO formats*!

In addition, each branch now has its own copy of the main code. Any common changes there have to be coordinated between the three branches. This is a major hassle. To make this work you'd need a *fourth* branch for the common code that everyone else branches off of. It's a lot of work and there's no benefit.

In conclusion, you're doing fine. Leave it the way it is.

---

In addition, as a Perl programmer you should be writing modules.  Instead of a library of functions in PDF.pl you should have a PDF formatter object in `lib/PDF.pm`. The main function creates the appropriate formatter and they all have the same interface.  This is a large topic, too big for this answer, and I encourage you to ask a question about it.

---

Back to your question. Let's pretend it's a good idea to split your project into three branches.

First thing to realize is Git branches are just labels pointing at a commit. Right now your repository looks something like this with the `master` branch pointing at commit C.

```
A - B - C [master]
```

First, make a branch for your changes. `git branch pdf`. Then check it out `git checkout pdf`. Now your repository looks like this with both `master` and `pdf` pointing at C.

```
A - B - C [master]
          [pdf]
```

Now delete the unwanted files with `git rm Excel.pl HTML.pl` and commit them with `git commit`. Voila! You now have a branch with just the PDF work. `master` remains safely at C.

```
          D [pdf]
         /
A - B - C [master]
```

Repeat for HTML and Excel. Just make sure you branch them from `master`! Checkout `master` first, then branch. Or you can make the branch point explicit with `git branch html master`. You can also use `git checkout -b html` to branch and checkout in one command.

Now you have this hydra of four branches.

```
          D [pdf]
         /
A - B - C - E [html]
 [master]\
          F [excel]
```

At this point, `master` is no longer needed and should be deleted. `git branch -d master`.

```
          D [pdf]
         /
A - B - C - E [html]
         \
          F [excel]
```

Now if you want to do work on the PDF code, you check out the `pdf` branch.

However any work to `main.pl` is also branched.  Any work done on `main.pl` will not be shared between the branches.  As I mentioned before, this defeats the point of modularization.  You'll have to either mess with `git cherry-pick` or have a more complicated branch structure where all work happens on a `common` branch (with no formatters) which everyone else merges with. I'm not going to try and draw that.

If this sounds overly complicated for your example, IT IS! You don't need to branch.

Comment: Okay, I was hoping for an easy answer, but you are correct about how to split it up. I'll probably create three new versions mostly because of the personalities involved. The only real changes I anticipate are in the output modules. BTW, it's actually PDF.pm (rather than PDF.pl as I stated. ) I also have other modules (such as SQL.pm) that I omitted for the sake of a less verbose question.